# apk file is not installed in any android phone with android 10,11,12 but install in android 9 or less

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I am an Android developer and I finished a project and built an apk file using Android Studio (create a key and then extract the apk file), but when I manually installed the application on my Xiaomi Android 11 phone, it showed me an error message shown in the picture, and when I tried it with my friends, the same problem occurred  On phones with Android 10, 11 and 12, but when I tested it on Android 9, the application was installed, so what is the solution to this problem??[the error message when installing the apk][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZWqR.jpg

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bodykh.IslamyatApp"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
location:19.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.rommansabbir:AnimationX:2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it from Android studio on device which has Android 10 or above? does it show any error message in your Android studio log? Also, can you check your targetSdkVersion in your build.gradle?

Comment: Yes i try to run the app by USB debugging on my phone android 11 but when i try to run the final release apk it isn't install and my target sdk is 30 @WilsonSim

Comment: Can you post the contents of `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Or what is the `minsdk` set in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Check your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` file(app level)

Comment: @BodyKh can you also check what is the compileSdkVersion in your Build.gradle?

Comment: i added my build.gradel file to the post  @Abhishek Dutt

Comment: @WilsonSim my compileSdkVersion is 31

Comment: @Android Geek my compileSdkVersion is 31 and targetSdkVersion is 31